# Asp.net Deployment (web installer)

Tags: asp.net, deployment, installation, web-deployment

I need to implement a web site installer for my asp.net application.  The installer will be handling following features -

1. Deploy the .net web application on to the IIS server
2. Setting up the Sql database connection to run the DB scripts.
3. Execute all the DB scripts.
4. Run another exe for the license management.
5. If some thing goes wrong, need to rollback everything.

I have heard about wix and install shield and wondering what would be the best technology suitable for this particular case.

Thanks Thurein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MSDeploy does all this and more. Find it over on www.iis.net.

-Oisin

Comment: Personally, I recommend that MSDeploy is the best way to handle the web deployment, because its nicely integrated with TFS and VS10.

Answer (score 1):

WIX has the advantage of being very flexible and free.  It also has a somewhat steep learning curve.  If you are going to be doing something like this frequently however, it is certainly worth the investment.

After that, there are any number of commercial options to choose from, i.e InstallShield.

Comment: I picked wix, because it meets my needs.  SQLExtension and IISExtension are doing well with custom action :).